# Authenticating application with Azure AD using X509 certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, webforms, x509

My Web Form application has to connect to Azure AD for Single-Signon. I have added an OWIN Startup class and added the code shown in the answer of this post:

[404 not found error when trying to initialize Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68452647/404-not-found-error-when-trying-to-initialize-azure-ad)

When I run the application, it gives "access denied".

I read about X509 certificates authentication in the below link and added the code in Login.aspx however, it is never reaching this code. It hits Startup.cs code of the above link and throws error "Access Denied":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#special-considerations-for-certificate-validation

I want to know whether X509 certificate code is also required and how it can be authenticated.

In the second link, check this section: "ASP.NET WebForms sample". I have added this code in Login.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

> Web Form application has to connect to Azure AD for Single-Signon

Thank you [soumi-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/50837/soumi-msft.html) Posting [your answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/98335/aspnet-webform-not-logging-through-ms-azure-ad-sso.html) to help other community members .

"Unfortunately, we do not have any samples published or available for ASP .Net WebForms. All that is available are MVC applications. You can find the list of available [samples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code) .

Having said that, since ASP .NET WebForms uses the traditional an event-driven model, I believe the ASP .NET WPF sample might help.  Please find the [sample here](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-desktop-msgraph-v2)  "

For more information Please refer the below Links:

.[ASP.NET Web Forms application to use Azure Active Directory .](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/convert-asp-net-webforms-with-windows-authentication-to-use-aad/) .

.[SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618815/azure-active-directory-sso-with-asp-net-webforms).&
[X.509 Client certificate credential | Git-Hub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/src/ClientCertificateCredential.cs) .